# Missing print options in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The "Print what" options in the Print dialog box that hold the :Hide collapsed regions" and "Include line numbers" seems to be missing in VS 2015.

Does anyone have any info on this? Have they moved?

VS 2013 print dialog.

[image: VS 2013 print dialog]

VS 2015 print dialog.

[image: VS 2015 print dialog]

Comment: Doesn't anyone have any idea where these print setting have gone.

Answer (score 0):

I too am saddened by the removal of these options. This is a "Known Issue" which was acknowledged in the first [release of the new print dialog plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ColorPrinting) (which became the built-in dialog with VS2015).

Printing line numbers *is* still supported (if you enable line numbers in the Text Editor, [they will be printed automatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/80f9d1c8-797a-4227-8f96-4b6f60ce04ed/cannot-print-line-numbers-in-vs2015-update-1-?forum=visualstudiogeneral)). However, hiding collapsed regions is *not* (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430065/how-do-i-not-print-collapsed-code-regions-in-visual-studio-2015?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Please consider [voting for this issue in the UserVoice site](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18703546-re-enable-ability-to-hide-collapsed-regions-when-p).