# How do I not print collapsed code regions in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm sure this is a foolish question, but I can't seem to find an answer.  I'm required to print out my code for a program, but I want to not print regions that are collapsed, as this would save about a dozen pages of paper per print.  Where is the setting in Visual Studio 2015 to do this, if there is one?  I am working in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut/Paste your collapsed regions into functions and put those functions into a different file. Its easy "low lying fruit" in terms of refactoring and making you code so much easier to read.

Regions are like totally gross

Comment: This along with partial classes makes it so you don't even need the functions in a separate class.

Comment: Great idea.  I hate regions too, I was just lucky enough to inherit them, but this is a simple solution to that. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

Prior to VS2015, the option to hide collapsed regions while printing was available on the Print dialog (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453718/missing-print-options-in-vs-2015)). Unfortunately, however, that feature has been removed (as noted in the "Known Issues" section of [this release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ColorPrinting)). Please consider voting to restore this capability on this [UserVoice Request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18703546-re-enable-ability-to-hide-collapsed-regions-when-p).